# submit button in the middle of form

Tags: css, html

My question is: 
May I put submit button not in the end of form, I need to put submit somewhere in the middle of form for comfort design layout. 
For example:

```
<form name="wide-search" action="/wide-search/" method="get" class="form-wide-search">
       <select class="form-control cars">
               <option>1</option>
               <option>2</option>
       </select>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск по всем объявлениям доски">
       <select class="form-control region-search">
               <option>1</option>
               <option>2</option>
       </select>
//HERE IS FORM SUBMIT BUTTON
       <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="searchInput" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Искать среди всех товаров и услуг" value="" x-webkit-speech="">
            <div class="input-group-btn"> 
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Найти</button>
            </div>
       </div>
//AND THEN WE HAVE SOME SELECT'S WITH PARAMETRES, THAT ALSO CONNECTED TO THIS FORM BUT THEIR 
PLACE IS AFTER SUBMIT BUTTON
       <select class="form-control mark">
               <option>1</option>
               <option>2</option>
       </select>
       <select class="form-control model">
               <option>1</option>
               <option>2</option>
       </select>
       <select class="form-control year">
               <option>1</option>
               <option>2</option>
       </select>
</form>
```

I need to create Html and Css design layout for this form, I get this task from programmer, and I'm not shur will this work true, or it is wrong layout. I didn't find answer in internet for this question. So I believe someone can explain me. In the end I add image of this form.[image]

Comment: It will work as long as it is inside the form but it is a common practice and logical to have it as the last item in the form.

Comment: Location doesn't matter. The button is tied to the form.

Comment: Simply move the button and click it.  You could have answered your own question faster than the time it took you to post it.

Comment: @Drew Kennedy So if I understand layout like this is possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the submit button anywhere inside the form. Also with the HTML5 [`form`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.submit.html#button.submit.attrs.form) attribute you don't even have to put it inside the form, e.g.

```
<form id="form-id">
   ...
</form>
<button type="submit" form="form-id">Submit from outside</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The location for where you place elements inside a form does not matter. A quick example would be:

[Submit Button On Top of Input](http://jsfiddle.net/02qtw8mj/)

Also, a submit button can be located outside the form with the the `form` attribute and the form's id.

[Submit Outside Form](http://jsfiddle.net/02qtw8mj/1/)